# How To Determine If A Certain Username Is A Valid SVN Username Without A Password In Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, svn

I'm using the following open source project, Svnplot:

https://bitbucket.org/nitinbhide/svnplot/wiki/Home

I'm getting a list of code reviewers. These usernames are supposed to be existing user names in svn. How can I actually check that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply: You can't. For a complete list of readers you need the config fileof the apache or svnserve config file. 
This does not mean you have a complete list as this files modification is not versioned(as it is a file on a server).

You can get a list of all committers, though:

For this you just need to analyze all revisions and add the authors.